# How to calculate how many days between two dates in c++ visual studio?

Tags: c++, .net, date, visual-studio-2013

I have just started learning C++ and I want to try to work with dates now. How can I calculate number of days between two dates?
I tried using TimeSpan and DateTime classes, but I can't get them to work..

I found this on other thread and something as simple as this would be great:

```
DateTime xmas = new DateTime(2009, 12, 25);
double daysUntilChristmas = xmas.Subtract(DateTime.Today).TotalDays;
```

Comment: It does not work because that code is not C++.

Comment: If you use CLR mode, it would be nice to say it. If you do not use is, please also say it. The example uses .Net classes, to you want to use them, or do you prefere to use the standard C++ library ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta It is not C++ because otherwise it would have read `DateTime*`. That *could* be C++/CLI but it's likely to be C#, which has a class DateTime.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to do this in C++ Visual Studio. What classes should I use? actually I don't know the difference between Standard and .NET, but the easier the better..

Comment: "in […] visual studio?" – oh wait, Visual Studio's got a date/time calculator feature?

Comment: Have you tried searching StackOverflow?  Looks like there are a bunch of related, if not duplicate, questions.

Comment: By the way, Visual Studio is a tool for developing C++, C#, C, and .NET/CLR languages to name a few.  Visual Studio is not a language.  *Be aware that Microsoft adds in features to the standard C and C++ language*, so what you are learning may not be standard C++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of days between two dates C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218894/number-of-days-between-two-dates-c)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of answers in StackOverflow. Try to use search.

For example this one is with good solution:
[Number of days between two dates C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218894/number-of-days-between-two-dates-c)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
  struct std::tm a = {0,0,0,24,5,104}; /* June 24, 2004 */
  struct std::tm b = {0,0,0,5,6,104}; /* July 5, 2004 */
  std::time_t x = std::mktime(&a);
  std::time_t y = std::mktime(&b);
  if ( x != (std::time_t)(-1) && y != (std::time_t)(-1) )
  {
      double difference = std::difftime(y, x) / (60 * 60 * 24);
      std::cout << std::ctime(&x);
      std::cout << std::ctime(&y);
      std::cout << "difference = " << difference << " days" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to use it with simple way (like in C#) you should use third-part libraries like this:
http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html

Comment: No worries, this was automated message that came from reviewing your answer. So you know for next time, it's better to include essential parts if the link stops working :)