# Cpp program two find number of days between two given dates, consol CMD

Tags: c++, date

```
//C++ program two find number of days between two given dates
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>

    using namespace std;

        // A date has day 'd', month 'm' and year 'y' 
    // 'h' hour , 'min' minute ; 'sec' second
    struct Date
    {
        int d, m, y, h, min, sec;
    };
```

Problem is in main :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);

    int test = stoi(line);
    unsigned int * tab = new unsigned int[test];
    for (int i = 0; i <test; i++)
        tab[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<test; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, line);
        int n1 = stoi(line);                     
        int n2 = stoi(line);
        tab[i] = getDifference(n1, n2);  // HERE IS PROBLEM 
    }   

    for (int i = 0; i<test; i++)
            {
                cout << tab[i] << endl;
            }
```

The error pops up:
No proper constructor to redirect "int" to "Date"

How to solve it?
My task is to download data through CMD, the first line is the number of tests, the next is 5 sets of dates to count the difference in days between them. Do you know how to tell the program that the first two lines are one set?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here. It's especially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: You should search the internet for examples, using search terms as "C++ find days between dates".  I very sure there are already similar questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of days between two dates C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218894/number-of-days-between-two-dates-c)

Comment: Already wrote, I have only a problem with the constructor of redirecting the element "int" to "date"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to read in each number separately into the members of a `Date`-object, and then compare `Date`-objects, not just single integers.
Strategy is to read in complete lines (e.g. "20 10 2017") and then use a `stringstream` for reading in the separate numbers:

```
#include <sstream>

struct Date
{
    int d, m, y, h, min, sec;
};

ostream& operator << (ostream& o, Date & d) {
    o << d.d << "/" << d.m << "/" << d.y;
    return o;
};

int main() {

    std::string line;
    if (std::getline(std::cin,line)) {
        int nrOfSets = 0;
        stringstream reader(line);
        reader >> nrOfSets;
        int i=0;
        Date previousDate;
        while (i < nrOfSets && getline(cin,line)) {
            Date d;
            reader = stringstream(line);
            if (! (reader >> d.d >> d.m >> d.y)) {
                cout << "invalid input." << endl;
                continue;
            }
            i++;
            if (i > 1) { // already two dates entered?
                cout << "calculating difference between " << d << " and " << previousDate << ":" << endl;
                // your code: int difference = calcDifference(d, previousDate);
            }
            previousDate = d;
        }
    }
}
```

Input / Output:

```
2
20 10 2017
22 10 2017
calculating difference between 22/10/2017 and 20/10/2017:
```

Comment: The program is great, but there was a problem when data was uploaded by CMD (file.exe is not recognized as an interial or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: How do you "build" your program, do you compile *and* link it? are you using an IDE, or are you calling `gcc` on your own?

Comment: For input data:
5
1997 12 31 0 0 0
1998 1 1 0 0 0
1997 12 31 23 59 59
1998 12 31 23 59 59
1997 12 31 23 59 59
1998 1 1 23 59 58
2000 2 20 0 0 0
2000 3 20 23 59 59
2000 2 29 0 0 0
2000 3 1 0 0 0
the correct result is:
1
365
0
29
1