# Solution doesn't work for number of days between two dates

Tags: c++, time, date-difference

I know this question has been asked a few times, and I'm asking again because I've got issues with existing solutions on SO.

My goal is to find number of days between `1900-01-01` and a given date. The date will be in the format as `yyyy-mm-dd` and the type is `std::string`.

The solution I've followed is https://stackoverflow.com/a/14219008/2633803

And below is my version:

```
std::string numberOfDaysSince1900v2(std::string aDate)
{
    string year, month, day;
    year = aDate.substr(0, 4);
    month = aDate.substr(5, 2);
    day = aDate.substr(8, 2);

    struct std::tm a = { 0,0,0,1,1,100 }; /* Jan 1, 2000 */
    struct std::tm b = { 0,0,0,std::stoi(day),std::stoi(month),std::stoi(year) - 1900 };

    std::time_t x = std::mktime(&a);
    std::time_t y = std::mktime(&b);

    double difference;
    if (x != (std::time_t)(-1) && y != (std::time_t)(-1))
    {
        difference = std::difftime(y, x) / (60 * 60 * 24) + 36526; //36526 is number of days between 1900-01-01 and 2000-01-01
    }

    return std::to_string(difference);
}
```

It worked fine until the given date comes to `2019-01-29` and `2019-02-01`. In both cases, the output is `43494`. And for the whole Feb, the output is 3 days less than expected. Then, when it comes to March 2019, the output is back to normal again.
Another case is `2019-09-03`, the output is `43710`, whilst the expected output is `43711`.

Why would this happen to these specific dates? I ran the solution step by step and closely watched the variables in the memory but couldn't explain it.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The solution you've followed uses 5 for June and 6 for July. Did you think that was a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The month should be represented as an integer between 0 and 11, not 1 and 12.

So

```
struct std::tm a = { 0,0,0,1,0,100 }; /* Jan 1, 2000 */
struct std::tm b = { 0,0,0,std::stoi(day),std::stoi(month)-1,std::stoi(year) - 1900 };
```

I would say there are other problems with your code. You cannot reliably initialise a `tm` like that (the order of fields within the struct is not guaranteed). Neither does `difftime` necessarily return a number of seconds (which you are assuming).